# Persist GoogleMaps map object between views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have decided to use AngularUI Map plugin to render Google Maps map within one of my views.

The template looks like this:

```
<div id="map">
<div ui-map="map" ui-options="mapOptions" id="map-canvas"
     ui-event="{'map-click': 'placeMarker($event, $params)'}">
</div>
</div>
```

The map is stored in the map scope variable of the controller. I've forced this behavior by explicitly creating this variable in the controller body: `#scope.map = {};`

What I would like is to externalize this map object to a service to avoid recreating it every time the view is accessed.

The service I wrote looks like this:

```
evee.factory('mapService', [function () {
    return {

    };
}]);
```

And the controller code looks like this:

```
var LocationController = function($scope, mapService) {

    $scope.map = mapService;

...
```

I can't make it work, the plugin always reinitializes the map.
Should I drop the usage of the plugin and adopt a solution such as this
[non-plugin solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180750/initialize-google-map-in-angularjs) ?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reuse an AngularJS template between page views for the same route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250652/reuse-an-angularjs-template-between-page-views-for-the-same-route)

Answer (score 0):

The [angular-gm](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-gm) module reuses map instances so there is no memory leak.

Without the module, it seems like this is a non-trivial problem to solve with Angular.